# How to run a combination of query and filter in elasticsearch?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am experimenting using elasticsearch in a dummy project in django. I am attempting to make a search page using [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl). The user may provide a `title`, `summary` and a `score` to search for. The search should match all the information given by the user, but if the user does not provide any info about something, this should be skipped.

I am running the following code to search for all the values.

```
client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search().using(client).query("match", title=title_value)\
    .query("match", summary=summary_value)\
    .filter('range', score={'gt': scorefrom_value, 'lte': scoreto_value})
```

When I have a value for all the fields then the search works correctly, but if for example I do not provide a value for the `summary_value`, although I am expecting the search to continue searching for the rest of the values, the result is that it comes up with nothing as a result.

Is there some value that the fields should have by default in case the user does not provide a value? Or how should I approach this?

---

UPDATE 1
I tried using the following, but it returns every time no matter the input i am giving the same results.

```
s = Search(using=client)

if title:
    s.query("match", title=title)

if summary:
    s.query("match", summary=summary)


response = s.execute()
```

---

UPDATE 2
I can print using the `to_dict()`.
if it is like the following then `s` is empty

```
s = Search(using=client)
s.query("match", title=title)
```

if it is like this

```
s = Search(using=client).query("match", title=title)
```

then it works properly but still if i add `s.query("match", summary=summary)` it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign back into `s`:

```
if title:
    s = s.query("match", title=title)

if summary:
    s = s.query("match", summary=summary)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the [Search example](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#search-example) that django-elasticsearch-dsl lets you apply aggregations after a search so...

How about "staging" your search? I can think if the following:

```
#first, declare the Search object
s = Search(using=client, index="my-index")

#if parameter1 exists
if parameter1:
    s.filter("term", field1= parameter1)

#if parameter2 exists
if parameter2:
    s.query("match", field=parameter2)
```

Do the same for all your parameters (with the needed method for each) so only the ones that exist will appear in your query. At the end just run

`response = s.execute()`

and everything should work as you want :D

Comment: thank you for this, I have updated my question above to include the part of the code i tried based on your answer. The problem is that now it seems like it is returning the latest entries and not what i am searching for. I tried searching using only title or only summary or both but every time the same results come up.

Comment: I'm curious... before s.execute(), how does s looks like? Probably printing it is not the best idea... Debug your code and see that the whole query is being sent

Comment: If you're debugging now, make sure that the if statements also are working properly. Are you receiving your parameters (title and summary) as None or 0 or "" when the user doesn't send them? How do they look like?

Comment: Also, in the Search object try to specify the index name (it should also accept wildcards).

Comment: i print using `to_dict()` and saw that `s` is empty before `execute()`. I have verified that it enters properly the if statements as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [Python ES Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#). It lets you manage multiple things related to your cluster: set mappings, health checks, do queries, etc.

In its method `.search()`, the body parameter is where you send your query as you normally would run it ({"query"...}). Check the [Usage example](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#example-usage).

Now, for your particular case, you can have a template of your query stored in a variable. You first start with, let's say, an "empty query" only with [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context-ex), just like:

```
query = {
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

From here, you now can build your query from the parameters you have.

This is:

```
#This would look a little messy, but it's useful ;)
#if parameter1 is not None or emtpy
#(change the if statement for your particular case)
if parameter1:
    query["query"]["bool"]["filter"].append({"term": {"field1": parameter1}})
```

Do the same for all your parameters (for strings, use "term", for ranges use "range" as usual) and send the query in the `.search()`'s body parameter and it should work as you want.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: I mentioned to use django but i skipped to mention that I am using the [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl). The code shown above is leveraging this library.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't use that library. After I read the docs, I can see that it was built on top of the Python ES library and it helps you to call its methods in a simpler way. I'll write another answer for you :)